# Retrieving a Manufacture Serial Number

Tags: c#, windows

So a school who contracts labor from where I work just keeps ordering new computers and we have to maintain a database of serial numbers to asset tags as well as rename the computers to reflect their asset tag. I have the SN's and AT's associated in a CSV file what I would like to do is write a c# application that gets the serial number from the computer its running on then query the server for its name. Does anyone know a way to do this (The stuff I've read hints it will be through system.management but I'm not finding anymore). unfortunately I wont have access to one of the target computers or even one of the same brand until I need it to work.

So is there any discrepancies between brands as to where they put their serial numbers?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the `SerialNumber` property of the `Win32_BaseBoard` WMI object:

```
using System.Management;

ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
    new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT Product, SerialNumber FROM Win32_BaseBoard");

ManagementObjectCollection information = searcher.Get();
foreach (ManagementObject obj in information)
{
    foreach (PropertyData data in obj.Properties)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", data.Name, data.Value);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

searcher.Dispose();
```

Source: [Retrieving Motherboard Serial Number using WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66273/Retrieving-Motherboard-Serial-Number-using-WMI)

Of course, this only works on Windows platform.

Comment: Thanks the weird think was that when I use BIOS not baseboard is works but I don't want to be there Monday debugging cause I made it work great with my Dell and not their Lenovos.

Comment: You're right, I just tried it with `wmic` and `Win32_BaseBoard` isn't recognized. It works with `BIOS` and `BaseBoard`, although `BaseBoard` doesn't appear to return the same value as `BIOS`. It could be manufacturer-specific. What's so bad about a little debugging? Without access to those specific machines, you'll never be 100% certain that it's going to work.

Comment: Well I'm in a time crunch but after some thought if I just append all the possibly usefull WMI information together then compare by doing a string.contains(). That should work great so long as the info is there but from what I'm seeing it should be. Anyways thanks for your help you've saved me several annoyed hours; my imaging process should now be fully automated.

Answer (score -2):

Open your command prompt then type the following command and hit enter

```
> wmic bios get serialnumber
```

Open your Powershell command prompt then type the following command and hit enter

```
> (Get-WmiObject win32_bios).SerialNumber
```